# how to solve the error Unsupported Gateway Type for Storage in whmcs using stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, whmcs

**I want to save the credit card details for future use and i want to save the data in whmcs database credit card last 4 digit or card_data in blobformat. I am using stripe payment gateway and whmcs.**

```
<?php
$command = 'AddPayMethod';//save the data in api format
$postData = array(
    'clientid' => $ca->getUserID(),//client id
    'type' => 'CreditCard', //credit card type
    'description' => 'Mohit - check',//account holder name
    'card_number' => '4640823519584356',//credit card number
    'card_expiry' => '0521',//credit card expiry date
    'gateway_module_name' => 'stripe'//payment method
);
$adminUsername = '';
$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername); //show the api result or error
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a little late, but I definitely wouldn't post a credit card and expiry, whether real or not - although of course it's now expired.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used any models, so you won't be able to use `$ca->getUserID()`. You also need to include WHMCS' init.php file. Try this instead:

```
<?php

use WHMCS\ClientArea;
require __DIR__ . '/init.php';
$ca = new ClientArea();

$command = 'AddPayMethod';//save the data in api format
$postData = array(
    'clientid' => $ca->getUserID(),//client id
    'type' => 'CreditCard', //credit card type
    'description' => 'Mohit - check',//account holder name
    'card_number' => '4640823519584356',//credit card number
    'card_expiry' => '0521',//credit card expiry date
    'gateway_module_name' => 'stripe'//payment method
);
$adminUsername = '';
$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername); //show the api result or error
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a little late, but just in case someone is Googling for this..

These days, credit cards are not saved this way; rather they're saved by a WHMCS payment gateway in tokenized form - that is, instead of saving the credit card number itself (as in your example) your payment gateway would call Stripe and it gives you a code (eg: "AH998232187E41392HB0471") which your WHMCS Stripe payment gateway would then save for you as a payment method.  Here you're trying to do something that would normally be done by the payment gateway.

Saving actual literal credit card details is really frowned on, as if your WHMCS is successfully attacked, bad guys could steal and misuse the credit card info from the database.  A token can't be stolen as it onluy allows a transaction between your business and the customer - it can't be used to pay other businesses, so is ideal from a security point of view.

You should also be able to save the payment card details as a payment method without doing a transaction, under WHMCS's customer menu option "Manage Payment Methods", and there are similar options at the admin level.

I'm sure you solved this two years ago, but just wanted to make sure there was a response here for others.